# How implement Angular2 RouteReuseStrategy with Lazy Load Modules?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Try to use

```
export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {}
```

But cant get url from root for lazy loaded module. Please, help to create cached handlers. Here my custom reuse strategy:

```
import {RouteReuseStrategy, DetachedRouteHandle, ActivatedRouteSnapshot} from '@angular/router';


export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

    handlers: {[key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle} = {};

    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        console.info('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldDetach', route);
        return true;
    }

    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
        console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:store', route, handle);
        this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path] = handle;
    }

    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldAttach', route);
        return !!route.routeConfig && !!this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
    }

    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
        console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:retrieve', route);
        if (!route.routeConfig) return null;
        return this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
    }

    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldReuseRoute', future, curr);
        return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
    }
}
```

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Did it so - seems work. If there is way better - tell me please.

http://pastebin.com/ZxZY0ekg